# Stream dynamically create file content via .NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm looking for some high-level guidance on how to architect a multi-tiered solution that will generate and stream large text file content to an Angular 6 web application via .NET MVC controllers. The system consists of a Web API service layer, a .NET MVC web application, and the Angular front end.

Because the files will take some time to generate I want to do this asynchronously through the entire stack - that is, to write each line and pass it through the stack to the browser client as it becomes available, rather than wait for the entire file to be produced on the server before sending it to the controller.

The service layer will generate the file and output it via a controller method. This controller method is called by a controller method in the web application, which is in turn called by an Angular service. Ultimately, I want the file to land on a user's desktop.

The file content will be generated in a manner similar to the following (this is a synchronous version). numberOfRows could be in the millions, which is why the files could take some time to generate.

```
    public string GenerateFile(int numberOfRows)
    {

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            output.Append("Row " + i.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }

        return output.ToString();

    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I suggest you use [TextWriter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead Stringbuilder, performance is better a lot.

Comment: Good point. Thanks! Any ideas on the broader question?